# rvis doesn't draw model correctly

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Kinetic via a Docker image on my Windows 10 machine.  I have xserver setup so I can run GUIs.  When I run RVIS and load the URDF for my IRB 120 it draws the mesh incorrectly.  I tried a fix posted in another thread but it didn't work.  Any ideas?   I've uploaded the image of what draws.

please note I've tried *export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

*[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369269/rvis-doesn%27t-draw-model-correctly/) by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2021-01-11**:
Are you using a http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher node?

**Comment by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) on 2021-01-11**:
not sure. the tube representation of the bot renders correctly and moves like it should.  I'll try.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-12**:
Please attach your image to your post, instead of linking to your google drive.

I've given you sufficient karma.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-12**:
The `RobotModel` display seems to be in error-mode. Could you expand it and tell us what those errors are?

Also:

> I tried a fix posted in another thread but it didn't work

"it didn't work" isn't very informative. Neither is "a fix".

**Comment by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) on 2021-01-12**:
I'm referring to *export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"* which is posted as a solve in another almost identical thread of a robot drawing like this in RVIS and it doesn't work for me so it isn't a fix for this issue

**Comment by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) on 2021-01-12**:
I am running a joint state publisher

**Comment by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) on 2021-01-12**:
Error on the *RobotModel* is *No transform from [base] to [common_world]* and that repeats for each joint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved by changing my *fixed frame* to *base* from *common_world*

---

Originally posted by [danzeeeeeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/67659/danzeeeeeman/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0